# Prove if $A\subseteq C$ or $B\subseteq C$ then $A\cap B\subseteq C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true please? I do not know how to prove it and I need to. There is nothing saying any of sets are not empty, so they probably can be. Can you help, please?

> Prove or show counterexample
>
> If $A\subseteq C$ or $B\subseteq C$ then $A\cap B\subseteq C$

Comment: What is the relationship between $A\cap B$ and $A$?

Comment: Simply prove that this is true in the two cases. If $A \subseteq C$ then... If $B \subseteq C$ then... In both cases you have $A\cap B \subseteq C$.

Comment: $A \cap B \subseteq A$ and $A \cap B \subseteq B$, so the result is pretty much immediate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x \in A \cap B$, so $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. Now one of $A \subseteq C$ or $B \subseteq C$ must hold. Say, $A \subseteq C$. Then from $x \in A$ we get $x \in C$ and we're done. Likewise if $B \subseteq C$ we get $x \in C$ too but now from $x \in B$. So we always have $x \in C$, whatever alternative holds. So $A \cap B \subseteq C$ is proven.